# Setting line space for a JTextarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

The default spacing between the lines of my textArea is too clumsy. I would like to increase the line spacing between the lines. Is there a way to achieve this for a textarea?

PS: I know that line spacing can be set for a `JTextPane` with `StyledDocument` and STyledConstants. My scope is limited to TextArea only and I would rather not prefer to replace my textarea with a textpane as it would mess up with some other functional dependencies in the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no *simple* way to do this. Per [the Swing Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) (emphasis mine):

> If you want the text area to display its text using multiple fonts or **other styles**, you should use an editor pane or text pane.

That said, the source for `JTextArea` shows that it's not declared `final`. If you *really* want to change the spacing, you could create a custom subclass. That wouldn't be trivial, though.